# Scraping after page is loaded with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page that has elements being created by JavaScript. When I pass through my script it does not give the full HTML. Is there a way to render the page first then obtain the HTML?

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/search"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

resLog = browser.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resLog, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is dynamically loaded from api calls json response via `XHR` as POST method.Here is an example how to grab all jobposts data and you can grab  all items whatever you want. Here I scrape only all `titles`.

**Program:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
body= {"appliedFacets":{},"limit":20,"offset":20,"searchText":""}
headers= {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
   }

api_url = "https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/wday/cxs/cibc/search/jobs"


jsonData = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers).json()

data=[]   
for limit in range(0,1726,20):
    jsonData['limit']= limit
    for item in jsonData['jobPostings']:
        title=item['title']
        data.append(title)
        #print(title)

df =pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["Title"])
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
                                     Title
0                                 Senior IT Manager PMO
1                  Financial Services Representative II
2     Mobile Mortgage Advisor Assistant -P/T OTTAWA,...
3                     Financial Services Representative
4                                    Dev Ops Consultant
...                                                 ...
1735  Vice-President, Private Wealth and Asset Manag...
1736                                     Technical Lead
1737                           Sr. Analyst, Procurement
1738              Sr. Financial Advisor - IIROC (Urban)
1739  Sr. Consultant, Vulnerability Management and C...

[1740 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

###### What happens?

There are different issues if you call the site:

- Depending on your location it will make a redirect
- Loading / rendering the content will need a moment

###### How to fix?

The magic is to **wait** - so use `WebDriverWait` to wait until the presence of expected elements is located:

```
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#mainContent li')))
```

or in combination with change of the url:

```
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.url_changes('https://current_page.com'))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#mainContent li')))
```

###### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/search'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.url_changes('https://current_page.com'))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#mainContent li')))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
data = []
for a in soup.select('#mainContent li a'):
    data.append({
        'title':a.text,
        'url':'https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com'+a['href']
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

|  | title | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Universal Banker I | https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/de-DE/search/job/Mississauga-ON/Universal-Banker-I_2213838 |
| 1 | Associate Business Advisor | https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/de-DE/search/job/Fort-Saint-John-BC/Associate-Business-Advisor_2209976-1 |
| 2 | Senior HR Business Partner | https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/de-DE/search/job/Toronto-ON/Senior-HR-Business-Partner_2215640 |
| 3 | Coffee Chat with a Recruiter Event (Contact Centres) (Bilingual French/English) (Montreal) | https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/de-DE/search/job/Montral-QC/Coffee-Chat-with-a-Recruiter-Event--Contact-Centres---Bilingual-French-English---Montreal-_2206804-1 |
| 4 | Financial Services Associate [Hourly] | https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/de-DE/search/job/Port-Perry-ON/Financial-Services-Associate--Hourly-_2214853 |
| 5 | Manager, Regulatory Supervision | https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/de-DE/search/job/Toronto-ON/Manager--Regulatory-Supervision_2209939-1 |
| 6 | Fraud Agent - Contact Centre - Regina (Remote) | https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/de-DE/search/job/Regina-SK/Fraud-Agent---Contact-Centre---Regina--Remote-_2216315-1 |
| 7 | Sr. Director, IT Quality Assurance | https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/de-DE/search/job/Toronto-ON/Sr-Director--IT-Quality-Assurance_2216110 |
| 8 | Senior BI Analyst | https://cibc.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/de-DE/search/job/Toronto-ON/Senior-BI-Analyst_2207685 |

...